# R: replace a value of a vector with multiple values

Tags: r, vector, replace, insert

Let's say, I have a vector `a` with `length(a) = l` and `l >= 1`.

The element `"x"` occurs at least one time in `a`, but we don't know an exact position.

I want to replace every `"x"` in `a` with the values `c(1,2,3)`

For example: `a = ("y","x","z")`, then I want the result after the replacement to be `a = ("y",1,2,3,"z")`.

I thought of doing it this way:

```
l <- length(a)
pos.x <- which(a == "x")

if(l == 1L & pos.x == 1L) {
  a <- c(1,2,3)
} else if (l > 1L & pos.x == 1) {
  a <- c(1,2,3,a[-1])
} else if (l > 1L & pos.x == l) {
  a <- c(a[-l],1,2,3)
} else if (l >= 3 & pos.x != 1 & pos.x != l) {
  a <- c(a[1:(pos.x - 1)],1,2,3,a[(pos.x + 1):l])
}
```

While this code does work, my question would be wether there is a more 'elegant' way to solve this problem, that needs less processing power, and that could replace more than one `"x"`.

Thank you!

Comment: `l` looks a bit much like `1` and confused me for a second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple vectorized solution with base R -

```
a <- c("y","x","z","y","x","z") # vector to search
b <- 1:3 # replacement values

a <- rep(a, 1 + (length(b) - 1)*(a == "x")) # repeat only "x" length(b) times

a[a == "x"] <- b # replace "x" with replacement values i.e. b

[1] "y" "1" "2" "3" "z" "y" "1" "2" "3" "z"
```

Comment: That is nice. You could make it more general with `rep(a, 1 + (length(b) - 1)*(a == "x"))`. +1

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using a `for` loop

```
a <- c("y","x","z","y","x","z")
b <- c(1,2,3)
```

The 'trick' is to create a list first, then replace all `"x"` with `b` and finally call `unlist`.

```
a_list <- as.list(a)
for(i in which(a_list == "x")) {
  a_list[[i]] <- b
}
```

Result

```
unlist(a_list)
#[1] "y" "1" "2" "3" "z" "y" "1" "2" "3" "z"
```

---

Please consider @Shree's answer!

Here is why:

```
n <- 1e6
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(c("x", "y", "z"), size = n, replace = TRUE)
b <- 1:3

library(microbenchmark)
benchmark <- microbenchmark(
  markus = markus(a, b),
  IceCreamToucan = IceCreamToucan(a, b),
  Shree = Shree(a, b)
)

autoplot(benchmark)
```

[image]

```
#Unit: milliseconds
#           expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq       max neval
#        markus 403.38464 467.03277 615.8078 556.74067 754.5117 1095.7035   100
#IceCreamToucan 401.34614 462.92680 602.1556 526.08280 687.8436 1422.0629   100
#         Shree  52.33867  65.32323 157.6680  97.34066 162.0638  650.2571   100
```

**functions**

```
markus <- function(a, b) {
  a_list <- as.list(a)
  for(i in which(a_list == "x")) {
    a_list[[i]] <- b
  }
  unlist(a_list)  
}

Shree <- function(a, b) {
  a <- rep(a, 1 + (length(b) - 1)*(a == "x"))
  a[a == "x"] <- b
  a
}

# from the comments
IceCreamToucan <- function(a, b) {
  a_list <- as.list(a)
  w <- which(a_list == "x")
  a_list[w] <- rep(list(b), length(w)) # changed your answer slightly here
  unlist(a_list)
}
```

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Please turn your comment into an answer. I am just updating the benchmark.